# How to change redirect URI?

Tags: django, redirect, dns, uri, django-allauth

I am trying to use Allauth to authenticate with Google however I get a URI mismatch error. The app is currently on a development server with a domain ex. live.example.com. I can change the domain within the Google app settings and my Django app to localhost and everything works. I am trying to use my domain with Allauth and it is not working

I tried changing the site_id and setting different values for that. I am able to use the response from Allauth and manually add the domain and everything works. But when the request is sent it sets the URL to localhost because it doesn't understand the proxy.

```
    Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:5500/accounts/google/login/callback/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/XXXXXX288-gm2jiuh2o8XXXXXXXXXcc6n11d4j5sr.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=5XXXX82XX

Learn more

Request Details
client_id=X9XXXXX82X8-gXXXXh2o88ejglkXXXcc6n11d4j5sr.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=http://localhost:5500/accounts/google/login/callback/
scope=email profile
response_type=code
state=XXXtpODloQK
access_type=online
```

Comment: I'm having a similar error.
In my case it seems that redirect_uri is using HTTP instead of HTTPS as expected by Google "valid URIs".

Comment: @Kaniabi how did you solve this? I'm having the same issue.